# Changing pin colour for active item on static map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0a0yo575/1/

There's no errors with the JS. As far as I can tell, it should remove the "red-point" class from whatever is clicked and replace it with the "green-point" class?

```
if (previousTarget) {
    previousTarget.className = "";
}

event.target.className = "green-point";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Javascript, but using jQuery I can easily fix your problem (I'm assuming this is OK since you have the `jQuery` tag on your question ;-) ). I've also made some minor changes to the CSS so the pins on the map are actually the correct size. Furthermore, I added a `cursor: pointer` to the pins so it's actually clear that you can click them. See fully working example below, or on Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0a0yo575/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.abs').click(function() {
    $('.abs').removeClass('green-point').addClass('red-point');
    $(this).removeClass('red-point').addClass('green-point');
    $('.link').css('font-weight', '');
    $('.link[data-marker="' + $(this).attr("id") + '"]').css('font-weight', 800);
  });

  $('.link').click(function() {
    $('.abs').removeClass('green-point').addClass('red-point');
    $('#' + $(this).data('marker')).removeClass('red-point').addClass('green-point');
    $('.link').css('font-weight', '');
    $(this).css('font-weight', 800);
  });

});
```

```css
    a {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .abs {
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 32px;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #termini {
      top: 37.5%;
      left: 61.8%;
    }
    #french {
      top: 45.5%;
      left: 55.1%;
    }
    #mark {
      top: 58%;
      left: 39.3%;
    }
    #hakkasan {
      top: 65%;
      left: 12.6%;
    }
    #american {
      top: 62%;
      left: 42.8%;
    }
    #experiment {
      top: 54%;
      left: 57.2%;
    }
    #milk {
      top: 37.3%;
      left: 39.5%;
    }
    #pig {
      top: 37.1%;
      left: 38.5%;
    }
    #opium {
      top: 55%;
      left: 55.7%;
    }
    div {
      position: relative;
    }
    div.img-responsive {
      width: 100%;
      height: 65.5%;
    }
    .red-point {
      background-image: url("http://s23.postimg.org/842300vmv/point.png");
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .green-point {
      background-image: url("http://s21.postimg.org/9u6n8t38z/green.png");
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s11.postimg.org/cbggzlpib/map.png">

  <div class="abs red-point" id="termini">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="abs red-point" id="french">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="abs red-point" id="mark">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="abs red-point" id="hakkasan">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="abs red-point" id="american">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="abs red-point" id="experiment">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="abs red-point" id="milk">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="ab red-point" id="pig">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="abs red-point" id="opium">
    <a onClick="turnGreen(event)"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<ol>
  <li class="link" data-marker="termini">
    <a>Bar Termini</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link" data-marker="french">
    <a>French House</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link" data-marker="mark">
    <a>Mark's Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link" data-marker="hakkasan">
    <a>Hakkasan (bar)</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link" data-marker="american">
    <a>Bar Americain at Brasserie Zedel</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link" data-marker="experiment">
    <a>Experimental Cocktail Club</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link" data-marker="milk">
    <a>Milk &amp; Honey</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link" data-marker="pig">
    <a>Blind Pig</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link" data-marker="opium">
    <a>Opium</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is amazing man thanks (I just need to work out how to pair this with the list underneath now). 

Are you saying that there's very little need to write your own JS these days because JQuery contains all the functions you could ever want / need?

Comment: Yeap! I can easily make the list below work for you too, if you'd like. Do you want like the item to show that is clicked (and the others are hidden)? Or do you want the list below to also trigger the marker color change to green?

Comment: Yeah vice versa I guess. so when the marker is clicked it highlights the word and when the word is clicked it changes the marker to green (the same as clicking the marker itself).

Comment: I have updated my original answer above. If this is want you meant, please don't forget to select it as the correct answer :). Hope you like it! Also, here's your new Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0a0yo575/4/ . Of course, right now it only makes the list item bold (font-weight 800), but you can replace this with any action you like ;)

Comment: jQuery is incredibly powerful, and I'd recommend it for all your future endeavours ;)

Comment: You're most welcome! Good luck, and let me know if you need any further help. I love these kind of projects!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `a` tag inside the `red-point` has no width and no height, so you cannot click it. Give them

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
```

And you can.