# Follow up Google Maps for Laurens Swart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

thanks for your help the other week. I had a follow up question from:

[Changing pin colour for active item on static map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576274/changing-pin-colour-for-active-item-on-static-map)

I would like to add a little info box in the top left corner of the map, that changes the text inside depending on what item is active, and is hidden when no item is active.

https://jsfiddle.net/0a0yo575/8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.abs').click(function() {
        $('.abs').removeClass('green-point').addClass('red-point');
        $(this).removeClass('red-point').addClass('green-point');
        $('.link').css('font-weight','');
        $('.link[data-marker="' + $(this).attr("id") + '"]').css('font-weight',800);
    });

    $('.link').click(function() {
        $('.abs').removeClass('green-point').addClass('red-point');
        $('#' + $(this).data('marker')).removeClass('red-point').addClass('green-point');
        $('.link').css('font-weight','');
        $(this).css('font-weight',800);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the question and who is Laurens Swart

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4065947/laurens-swart

Comment: You should place an actual question in the title and in the body, **ask** something.

Comment: Do you think you can post a question with a user's name and it's like a private message to them?  That's not how this works..

Comment: You can't send pm's on SO, how else am I supposed to do it?!

Comment: Lol, I just found this page by Googling my own name >.< Do you still need help with this @DFGD ? If you do, just reply to this comment, that's the easiest way to make it pop up in my notifications ;-)